# How to get the scheduler of an already finished job in Yarn Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, scheduler, cloudera

So I'm in this situation, where I'm modifying the mapred-site.xml and specific configuration files of different schedulers for Hadoop, and I just want to make sure that the modifications I have made to the default scheduler(FIFO), has actually taken place.

How can I check the scheduler applied to a job or a queue of jobs already submitted to hadoop using job id ?

Sorry if this doesn't make that much sense, but I've looked around quite extensively to wrap my head around it, and read many documentations, and yet I still cannot seem to find this fundamental piece of information.

I'm simply trying the word count as a job, changing scheduler settings in mapped-site.xml and yarn-site.xml.
For instance I'm changing property "yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class" to "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler" based on this link : [see this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setting_up_ResourceManager_to_use_CapacityScheduler)

I'm also moving appropriate jar files specific to the schedulers to the correct directory.

For your reference, I'm using the "yarn" runtime mode, and Cloudera and Hadoop 2.

Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: It will probably help a lot if you can post an actual code example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: When you inspect the job id in the YARN UI, does it not tell you the scheduler?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the hint.I'm using the quickstart.cloudera.com/"portnumber" to see my jobs. Is that the same as Yarn UI? Anyway, when I go there, I can only see the metrics for different job ids, by clicking on that job. There is no information about scheduler.

Comment: @levininja Thanks for your help. I'm simply trying the word count as a job, changing scheduler settings in mapped-site.xml  and yarn-site.xml. For instance I'm changing property "yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class" to "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler" based on this : hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html
  Also moving appropriate jar files specific to the schedulers to the correct directory. Can you help me more on which part of the process's code might help you better understand my problem?

Comment: @mani I don't have the expertise to help with this problem, but if you take your last comment and edit your question to have that information, that will make it a lot more likely that someone will be able to answer it.

Comment: I didn't think you can apply the scheduler for a certain job or queue. I've always just configured all of YARN to use the same one

Comment: @levininja Thanks for your great suggestion. Done.

Comment: @cricket_007 I see. Maybe you are right. But from reading the documentation I thought such a thing is indeed possible. Anyway, provided that the configuration is for all jobs/queues, how may I get the scheduler information, if I've changed it through time? I bet it must have been stored somewhere.

Comment: In Cloudera Manager or Ambari, there is a configuration history. Outside of that, I am not aware of any configuration changelog

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your help. One more question, if I want to change the default scheduler, to say Fair scheduler and Capacity Scheduler, should I change it to Fair scheduler in both mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml, or only in one of them? In documentation, for capacity it only modifies yarn-site.xml and for Fair only modifies mapred-site.xml, which does not make sense to me at all.

Comment: Hmm. Cloudera documentation says yarn-site.xml https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_fair_scheduler.html#concept_gvd_gqn_2v

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you again, you are a life saver. How do I restart the job tracker once I've made the changes for the changes to take effect? I've tried" sudo service hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker restart " on command line, but it does not recognize the service. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You would use Cloudera Manager to restart... I highly doubt you are running `hadoop-0.20` anyway, that's almost a decade old. I don't know what services are installed on your machine.